# facing Error in pandas all arguments of StringMethods.split

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to machine learning. Please can you help me out? from below warning

**My Code**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.Keywords_List.str.split(' ', 1).tolist(), columns=['Subject', 'Keyword'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1.Keyword.str.split('(', 1).tolist(), columns=['Keyword', 'Count'])
```

**Error**

```
FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas all arguments of StringMethods.split except for the argument 'pat' will be keyword-only.
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.Keywords_List.str.split(' ', 1).tolist(), columns=['Subject', 'Keyword'])

FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas all arguments of StringMethods.split except for the argument 'pat' will be keyword-only.
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1.Keyword.str.split('(', 1).tolist(), columns=['Keyword', 'Count'])
```

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the call signature,

```
split(self, pat=None, n=-1, expand=False)
```

you are supplying the `n` parameter as a positional argument. This is a warning. It works now, but will fail in the future. To get rid of the warning, make it a named parameter

```
df.Keywords_List.str.split(' ', n=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll consider your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

The console is printing a warning that the .split() your using in your code will require all arguments to be keyword only.
You currently have "split(' ', 1)" in your code, and should work fine at the moment. When this change takes place, you will have to type in "split(' ', n=1).
Below are the keywords for .split().

```
Series.str.split(pat=None, n=- 1, expand=False, *, regex=None)
```