# FutureWarning Pandas Error for Split Function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, future-warning

I am cleaning my dataset to prepare it for analysis, and I have several lines of code that look like this:

```
referrals[['First Name','Last Name']] = referrals['Victim'].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)
```

The 'Victims' column holds the full name, and I need to split that column into 'First Name' and 'Last Name'. I am getting a FutureWarning that reads the following:

```
FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas all arguments of StringMethods.split except for the argument 'pat' will be keyword-only.
```

Can someone clarify what the new Pandas update will be doing that will nullify the way I'm writing the syntax currently? And what will be the updated ver to write the code so that I can prevent this FutureWarning from occurring? Thanks!

Tried to search up answers on Stack Overflow and couldn't seem to find an elucidating, satisfying answer.

Comment: The warning asks you to do `split(' ', n=1, expand=True)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [facing Error in pandas all arguments of StringMethods.split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73886976/facing-error-in-pandas-all-arguments-of-stringmethods-split)

Comment: Just as the error explains you need to use kwargs. df[['First Name', 'Last Name']] = df['Victim'].str.split(pat=' ', n=1, expand=True)